# Kafka failed to start when running Confluent start command on Docker Ubuntu image (Name or service not known)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apache-kafka, localhost, confluent-platform

I am trying to start Confluent on a running docker image for ubuntu. Here is the error for the command:

```
root@linuxkit-025000000001:/# /my/dir/path/confluent-4.0.0/bin/confluent start
```

Here is the output log:

> Starting zookeeper
>
> zookeeper is [UP]
>
> Starting kafka
>
> |Kafka failed to start
>
> kafka is [DOWN]
>
> Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment

I tried to start Kafka using :

```
# cd confluent-4.0.0
# ./bin/kafka-server-start ./etc/kafka/server.properties
```

Here is the IMPORTANT error log:

> Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> java.net.UnknownHostException: linuxkit-025000000001: linuxkit-025000000001: Name or service not known

What is the solution to run Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint to solution :
https://github.com/ModernMT/MMT/issues/276

I should add the hostname to the hosts. For my own solution I add a new line for 127.0.0.1 to be linuxkit-025000000001 as it is available from hostname command:

```
 # hostname
```

then I tried to edit /etc/hosts

```
# (printf "127.0.0.1  " ; hostname ) >> /etc/hosts
```

now Confluent can start successfuly!

Comment: I tried to do this, but I found that docker would clobber it when trying to run the image. :(